# Database Error while launching application

Tags: c#, sql

I deployed C# application and created installer. Installer gets created successfully but when tried to launch the application it throws up following error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file CampusPointe.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

connection string in app.config is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="App_Key_Management.Properties.Settings.VendorKeyConnectionString1" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Program Files\Vendor Key Management\VendorKey.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sri

Comment: CampusPointe.mdf? Where does that file come into the picture?

Comment: Primary database files are stored in *.mdf files.  Did you install SQL server express on Windows Server 2008?  When you did the install, did you save some files on a network shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

Sri,

First of all, you need to ensure a couple of things:
1. You have installed SQL Server
2. You need to deal with the creation or replacement of the file you created.  I think this is your issue ... If the .mdf file exists then you need to either update the existing file or drop and replace it (USE [database] GO DROP TABLE... GO CRATE TABLE ... GO).  You will also need to consider step 4 below.
3. If you are accessing a a file located in a database you need a fully formed name.  You also need to add the database user to the connection string in ASP.NET Web.Config or App.config (depending on the app).  I looks like you have started this ...
4. Make sure the user account that you are using in the connection string has the necessary privileges on the database side.  If this is a full fledged database in SQL SERVER then the user account will need update, delete, create privileges.  If you are replacing or creating databases on the fly then the user will need CREATE DATABASE or DROP / CREATE privileges.

I think to best answer your question we would need more information on the architecture of the application.  My guess is that your code creates the database fine the first time and then when you try to run it the second time it fails because the database is already there.  If this is the case you also need to address your code (with IF statements or SWITCH CASE ... your call) to handle situations where the table (1) does not exist and needs to be created; (2) exists and needs to be updated; and / or (3) exists and needs to be replaced.  The correct answer again depends on your code and what you are trying to do.